# Why is the output of this paste command split on separate lines with indents?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, paste

I was trying to merge files using either of these commands:

```
paste data_{1..2}.txt > 1_2.txt

paste <(awk '{print $1}' data_2.txt ) <(awk '{print $1}' data_2.txt) > 1_2.txt
```

But the columns in the output *don't line up*. I tried to clean tabs and spaces but I still get the same result. Here is my sample data below for *data_1.txt*:

```
TMAX
34.2481
19.1582
-0.903817
-0.408851
-0.849964
0.596377
0.922126
-5.13179
-17.4449
-15.1031
-12.5849
-12.2548
```

...and for *data_2.txt*:

```
TMAX
33.629
18.5924
-1.37411
-1.00714
-1.48201
0.0046866
0.295162
-5.69127
-18.0672
-15.7163
-13.1048
-12.8443
-11.9689
```

The combined *output*:

```
TMAX
    TMAX
34.2481
    33.629
19.1582
    18.5924
-0.903817
    -1.37411
-0.408851
    -1.00714
-0.849964
    -1.48201
0.596377
    0.0046866
0.922126
    0.295162
-5.13179
    -5.69127
-17.4449
    -18.0672
-15.1031
    -15.7163
```

What is expected of course is for the columns to line up like so:

```
TMAX    TMAX
34.2481 33.629
19.1582 18.5924
-0.903817   -1.37411
-0.408851   -1.00714
-0.849964   -1.48201
0.596377    0.0046866
0.922126    0.295162
-5.13179    -5.69127
-17.4449    -18.0672
-15.1031    -15.7163
-12.5849    -13.1048
-12.2548    -12.8443
-11.371 -11.9689
```

Why am I getting the distorted output with lines split and indentation?

Comment: Does `cat -et data_1.txt` show any weird output?

Comment: Yes it does. Here is the weird output TMAX^M$
34.2481^M$
19.1582^M$
-0.903817^M$
-0.408851^M$
-0.849964^M$
0.596377^M$
0.922126^M$
-5.13179^M$
-17.4449^M$
-15.1031^M$
-12.5849^M$
-12.2548^M$
-11.371^M$
-7.87503^M$
-13.6309^M$
-21.1465^M$

Comment: Your files ends with `\r\n` instead of `\n`. Just remove `\r` and try `paste` again.

Comment: @Gnouc, Thank you for pointing out my problem. I removed them using dos2unix data_2.txt

Comment: The title could be edited to better describe the problem for people who are later Googling for similar things, but I can't think of a better one myself... Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your files contain some special characters, like carriage return `\r\n`. You can check using:

```
cat -et file
```

If has, you should remove `\r` before using `paste`:

```
tr -d '\r'
```